# How can I reconnect to websocket URI using tomcat API

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I use tomcat API to connect websocket URI. Time to time I receive disconnect from server. I want to handle this and reconnect.
Here is how I connect to URI:

```
container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(10240000);
container.connectToServer(o, new URI(URI));
```

Further I receive error and handle it in

```
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    session.close(); // current session (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession)
    container.connectToServer(o, new URI(URI));
}
```

But I get

> CloseReason: code [1006], reason [Unexpected Status of SSLEngineResult
>   after an unwrap() operation]
>
> The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed while
>   subscribe to.. javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request
>   to initiate the WebSocket connection failed